# How to shift imageView inside table view on Click of button Outside the tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, button, tableview

I am building a cart inside a tableView, for that I need a check button which will appear when I will click on a button outside the tableView, So that I can select the items of that cell also I want to know what action should be performed to parse the information of the selected cell to array?

Comment: I am making a tableViewCell in which I want to slide the content to the right on click of button outside that tableView.

Comment: Means you set content in table view and when you click on button while table's content remove from table and set out side the table and set in main view ...?

Comment: no sir, it will only slide to right by 25 px.

Comment: here can't understand proper so please set your proper question here so we can understand what you want..?